# Почему RewriteRule в .htaccess не работает, если в регулярном выражении будут присутствовать русские символы?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Почему **RewriteRule** в **.htaccess** не работает, если в регулярном выражении будут присутствовать русские символы?

Если к примеру будем переходит по адресу [http://mysite/war/танк_т34](http://mysite/war/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D1%8234)

Так **работает**, перейдёт на страницу

```
 RewriteRule ^war/(.+)$ web/index.php?r=tank/my&page=$1 [L]
```

Так **не работает**, почему?

```
 RewriteRule ^war/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9ё_]+)$ web/index.php?r=tank/my&page=$1 [L]
```

Так **не работает**, почему?

```
 RewriteRule ^war/танк_т34$ web/index.php?r=tank/my&page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Современные браузеры вас обманули. Таких адресов не бывает :) Попробуйте скопировать адрес из адресной строки в текстовый редактор чтобы увидеть как он выглядит на самом деле.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov То есть нужно добавить те символы которые есть в шестнадцатеричной системе исчисления? Дело в том что до того как задать свой вопрос, и пытался эти символы добавить в регулярное выражение, и ничего не работало так-же.

Comment: вот - `([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9ё_%]+)`  не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^war/([a-zA-Z0-9_\%]+)$ web/index.php?r=tank/my&page=$1 [L]
```

Вот так должно было работать, но как выяснилось опытным путем в RewriteRule попадает не чистая [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), а строка в кодировке Apache по умолчанию, в моем случае это cp1252.

Лучшим вариантом в этой ситуации будет оставить вариант:

```
RewriteRule ^war/(.+)$ web/index.php?r=tank/my&page=$1 [L]
```

и далее обрабатывать ссылку, например через функцию [urldecode()](https://php.ru/manual/function.urldecode.html) там, где это нужно.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Я сам ещё до того как задать вопрос, пытался вставить знак `%`, правда его не экранировал.

Comment: Проверил у себя на тестовом, получил вот что:

Comment: `The requested URL /test/war/Ñ‚Ð°Ð½Ðº_Ñ‚34 was not found on this server`

т.е. апач воспринимает url в кодировке CP1252, поэтому не работает

Comment: У меня в логах апача `%D0%BF HTTP/1.1" 404` на букву `п`

Comment: Это работает `([^\x00-,.-@[-^`{-\x7F]+)` разрешить все символы не-ASCII  Но смыла наверное нету, лучше уж поставить как было со всеми символами `(.+)`

Comment: Отредактируйте Ваш ответ и я поставлю его верным. Большое Вам спасибо за помощь и отзывчивость!